# Providing a custom 401 response message on OpenId OnRedirectToIdentityProvider

Tags: c#, .net-core, openid-connect, openid

I'm using `AddOpenIdConnect` and need to modify the response in case the `OnRedirectToIdentityProvider` event is raised. Within this event the response status is modified to 401 and I would like to set a custom message. To write this custom message, I've created the `SetResponseBody` method.

The solution of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48216027/1974344) is used to set the response status, but I need to modify the Body as well.

I'm calling the `SetResponseBody` method (a custom method which I implemented) in order to modify the response body as soon as the `OnRedirectToIdentityProvider` event is raised from `AddOpenIdConnect`.'

As mentioned in one of the comments by @Panagiotis Kanavos in the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66915228/1974344), the `SetResponseBody` method doesn't seem to be a correct solution (despite the response actually contains valid json). Could you provide an alternative?

Summarized: I would like to return a custom response besides the status code 401.

```
OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = async e =>
{
    // e is of type RedirectContext
    if (e.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api")))
    {            
        if (e.Response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            e.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            // TestMessage is a const
            // e.Response is readonly (get) so it's not possible to set it directly.
            await ResponseRewriter.SetResponseBody(e.Response, TestMessage);
        }
        e.HandleResponse();
    }
    await Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

with `ResponseRewriter.SetResponseBody` defined as follows

```
public static async Task SetResponseBody(HttpResponse response, string message)
{   
    var originalResponseBody = response.Body;
    var responseBody = new MemoryStream();
    response.Body = responseBody;
    response.ContentType = "application/json";
    var body = new { Message = message };
    string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(body);
    await response.WriteAsync(json);
    response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    await responseBody.CopyToAsync(originalResponseBody);         
}
```

The last two lines are implemented as written in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54879170/getting-empty-response-on-asp-net-core-middleware-on-exception).