# .net 6 webapi disable auto redirect to login page for global [Authorize]

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-6.0

i use CookieAuthentication for .net 6 webapi with controllers (not minimal).

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

and set global authorize for all controllers and methods who is not set [AllowAnonymous]

```
app.MapControllerRoute("default", "api/{controller}/{action}/{id?}").RequireAuthorization();
```

after request i receive 302 redirect to
[image]

how can i disable auto redirect in .net 6 with global authorize ?

Comment: Can you tell us why you want to disable the auto redirect behavior? If you prevent it, it might display the 401-Unauthorized error? Are you sure you want do that?

Comment: because its not web view as MVC for redirect to login page, its API. I have external library what should receive 403 Forbiden or 401 Unauthorized status code without 302 by HTTP standart

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To prevent the Web API redirect to the Login page and show the 401 error, you can override the Cookie Authentication's OnRedirectToLogin event:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied =
    options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = c =>
    {
        c.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    };
});
```

After that, when you access the protected action method (the user is not authenticated), it will show the 401 error. Refer to this [github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/9039).

Comment: yes its work! a strange thing that webApi offers me to go logipage by default...

Comment: There's a way to restrict this to a single controller?

Comment: @skini82 https://stackoverflow.com/a/48216027/2879579

Comment: access denied should be 403 btw